# Could not find libmount

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, embedded, buildroot

During compilation of customized distribution (using buildroot v. 11.2018) 
I have problem with libmount library (the problem appeared after I had included efl package in buildroot menuconfig - *Target packages -> Graphic lib... -> efl* ). 
I have additionaly installed package libmount-dev with no results.

```
checking for getxattr in -lc... yes
checking sys/xattr.h usability... yes
checking sys/xattr.h presence... yes
checking for sys/xattr.h... yes
checking for XATTR_NOFOLLOW... no
checking for LIBMOUNT... no
configure: error: *** Could not find libmount
```

How to include this library to obtain succesful compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libmount-dev` on your system will not change anything: what is missing here is libmount for the target system, not on the build machine. libmount is provided by the util-linux package.

What is your Buildroot configuration ? EFL should only need libmount if BR2_PACKAGE_EFL_UTIL_LINUX_LIBMOUNT is enabled. So if you reach this situation with BR2_PACKAGE_EFL_UTIL_LINUX_LIBMOUNT disabled, then there is a bug in Buildroot.

Could you fill in a bug in the Buildroot bug tracker at https://bugs.busybox.net/, specifying the exact Buildroot version you're using, and attaching your Buildroot .config file that allows to reproduce the issue ?

Also, please make sure that this error happens after a completely clean build, i.e "make clean && make".

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem when I got to build `libglib2` in Buildroot-2019.02.5 (`mc` dependency). `libmount` was checked (Target packages -> System Tools -> util-linux -> libmount) but `make libglib2-configure` failed. Problem was solved after I turned on `mount/umount` utility in `util-linux` configuration, rebuilt it and whole rootfs.

```
make util-linux-dirclean
make util-linux-build
make
```